# Why does Hibernate execute multiple queries for updating children when parent is updating?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a many-to-one relationship with `inverse="false"` and `cascade="all"`. When I update the parent, there is an update query for this parent object and multiple update queries - one for each child object in child's collection.

Could you tell me why there are these queries for children? And how might I avoid them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have cascade="all" that means that every operation on parent entity will call same operation on child entities. So you have to remove cascade=all if you want not to cascade operations on child entities from association.

But you should be careful with that configuration, because if you don't have cascade persist (for example) created child entity will not be persisted even it is created regularly, but you have to explicitly call save on every child entity.

You can read more about cascade types [on this thread.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades)

Answer (score 0):

You want to to prevent `Hibernate` from updating the children entities you should change the cascade type, remove `cascade=all`.